# Simple Question: Derivative of a path

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I have a path `V[t_]:={3t^2,2,6t}`, and I define `F[t_]:=V[t]/Norm[V[t]]`.
I simply want the derivative of `F`, which is a 3-vector function of the variable `t`.
Somehow I did not manage to find any (simple?) way to calculate it..
Ideas?

Comment: You might want to use `V[t]/Sqrt[V[t].V[t]]` instead.

Comment: Alternatively, you have to use `Assuming` or the `Assumptions` when you will simplify the derivative of the function `F`

Comment: Thanks... I also didn't notice in my attempts.., that Mathematica was still complaining about an ancient error, hidden behind my window...

Comment: @Dror And you are sure you want this instead of the *normalized derivative of v*, which is the direction vector along the path?

Comment: @halirutan , thanks for the nice tip. Though, In my case (which, regretfully, I did not specify), `V` is actually the derivative of my original path, and I wanted to find It's normal.

Answer (score 1):

You don't specified what your actual problem is and what exactly you have tried. Isn't this simple enough?

```
v[t_] := {3 t^2, 2, 6 t};
f[t_] := v[t]/Sqrt[v[t].v[t]]

D[f[t], t]
```

Comment: Yes, that works. Somehow It didn't work when using `Norm[]`. Thanks! (In my next questions, all will be specified! :) )